# How to make AngularJS directive to clearly define its dependencies without isolating scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, directive

I'm writing my application's directives in a way of making used of isolated scope to clearly defined its dependencies in the parent scope. So I can always achieve this in my HTML component

```
<my-directive dependency-one="x" dependency-two="y"></my-directive>
```

This is the code for my directive

```
angular.module("myapp").directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                dependencyOne: '=',
                dependencyTwo: '='
            },
            templateUrl: "path/to/myDirective.html",
            link: function($scope){
                //here goes the code for linking function
            }
    }
}]);
```

However, I've read some best practises in AngularJS community stated that we should avoid using Isolated Scope as much as possible, as it will increase the app's watchers and useless bindings. Only used Isolated Scope when you're writing component which is reused over the application.

As far as I know, we have two possibilities which this:

- our directive does not create a child scope
- our directive create a child scope, which is prototypal inherit the parent scope

We can prevent creating new scope and unnecessary bindings this way, but it will decrease the readability and clarity of directive's HTML markup, now we only have something like:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Looking at this code, I don't have an idea of what is required for the directive to perform, which is against the advantage of "declarative html" that AngularJS introduced.

Anyone interested in this problem?

Comment: without isolated scope can still have attributes and access those values. Still lots of power under the hood of a directive to do lots of things with attributes

Comment: I have think about it and try it, but i don't like the way its interpolate the attributes. With primitive, it's ok to have interpolated value displayed on the HTML, but for eg. when you want to pass an object via directive's attributes, it will print out the json, which look ugly in the HTML tag.

Comment: i was only mentioning it since you went to the extreme of showing nothing but a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Without Isolated scope, it would be very difficult to have a clear Directive API.
Therefore, I don't completely agree with "*I've read some best practises in AngularJS community stated that we should avoid using Isolated Scope as much as possible, as it will increase the app's watchers and useless bindings*"

If you want clear dependency, you must go for isolated scope. 
There are ways to reduce the number of watches and bindings.
Content on following url may be helpful in this case. @ http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2014/11/the-top-5-mistakes-angularjs-developers.html